# Add active class for menu list based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add `active` class based on `url` to show that which `li` is clicked.

```
pageUrl = location.pathname;
$('#sidebar-left nav li.active').removeClass("active");
if (pageUrl) {
  $('nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
}
```

this is what I have tried in `init()` method.
I am getting the `pageUrl` correctly.But am unable to add active class for clicked  `li`.

html:

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
            <ul class="nav main-menu">
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope">
                            <a href="/pay/paymanagement" ng-click="tabName(child.name)" class="ng-binding">slips</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
```

`Note:` I can add `active` class using `url` only. Because each `li` has different pages so whenever I click the `li`, page will be refreshed.so I cant css/onclick/.click here.

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: This is `jQuery` so why you tagged `angularjs` ?

Comment: give this `console.log($('nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])'))` inside `if` condition and check whether you are getting the DOM there

Comment: I thought there may be some other way in angularjs to achieve this.

Comment: @AswinRamesh this is what I got.. `r.fn.init(0)
length
:
0
prevObject
:
r.fn.init [document]
__proto__
:
Object(0)`

Comment: @laz this means the element you are searching for doesn't exist in the page, it might be because the `pageUrl` may have the full URL, whereas you `a` tag will only have the relative path

Comment: check your pageUrl using console.log(pageUrl).

Comment: Show us your HTML code.

Comment: @AswinRamesh I am sure that my `pageUrl` only have clicked `li href` beacuse am using `location.pathname`.please check it.

Comment: Html code added.Please check.

Comment: okay... @laz I think you missed the dot `.` in front of `nav` it should be `$('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active")`

Answer (score 2):

When you set an href url it automatically turns to full URL in JavaScript. So pathname in your code won't work. Instead lets use the `filter()` method from jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $('#sidebar-left nav li.active').removeClass("active");
    $('#sidebar-left nav li a').filter(function(){
        return this.href.indexOf(window.location.href) !== -1;
    }).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: let me try:-):-)

Comment: It should work. I checked lbu code it is working for me.

Comment: I think am adding my code in wrong place.page is getting refreshed after clicking the menu.so added active class may be hide right?

Answer (score 1):

you missed the dot `.` in front of nav class

It should be like

```
$('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
if (pageUrl) {
  $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
}
```

it should work if your `location` returns correctly, a minimal code you can find it here

*NB: I have hardcoded the URL*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageUrl = '/employee/Home'
  $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
  if (pageUrl) {
     $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
            <ul class="nav main-menu">
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
                    </a>                       
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-click="tabName(parent.name)">
                        <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope">
                            <a href="/pay/paymanagement" ng-click="tabName(child.name)" class="ng-binding">slips</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: still am facing the same probem :-(

Comment: @laz can you tell what it gives you now `console.log($('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])'))` inside the `if`

Comment: it gives the same thing..which I posted initially :-(

Comment: I think am adding my code in wrong place.page is getting refreshed after clicking the menu.so added active class may be hide right?

Comment: so if in that case, can you add it in document ready, like in my snippet

Comment: am using angular.So I added it in `init()` method.

Comment: are you using angular? why did you combine both jquery and angular? also angular2 or 1?

Comment: angular1.. am using angular only for data binding

Comment: why am getting `length 0` here `$('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])')`. Your code is working fine but why am getting length 0.

Comment: are you using it inside controller?, if so move it you directive and add the code to your `link` section

Comment: If in controller, then it is trigger before the view is getting rendered, so will have to use it in directive refer,
 http://websystique.com/angularjs/angularjs-custom-directives-link-function-guide/

Comment: Is this correct? `.directive('addActive', [function() {
    return{
        ...
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
             
                pageUrl = location.pathname;
                $('#sidebar-left .nav li.active').removeClass("active");
                if (pageUrl) {
                    debugger
                    console.log($('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])'))
                    $('.nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').addClass("active");
                }
        }
    }
}]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163616/discussion-between-laz-and-aswin-ramesh).

Comment: can able to add `active` class  now.But its adding to the content of the `url`.its not adding to the li which has `current url` has `href`.Whats wrong here?

Comment: to the content? you used the above code right?? `addClass` function

Answer (score 1):

Iam using this script for adding class active to the a element when the url matched with current page url.

```
$(function(){
       pageUrl = location.pathname;
       $('nav ul li a').each(function () {
            link = $(this);
            if (link.attr("href") == pageUrl) {
                link.addClass("active");
            } 
       });
   });
```

The element structure look like below:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/test/a/">Testing</a>
            <a href="/test/b/">Testing</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For your case, you could use this code:

```
$(function(){
       pageUrl = location.pathname;
       $('#sidebar-left ul li a').each(function () {
            link = $(this);
            if (link.attr("href") == pageUrl) {
                link.parent().addClass("active");
            } 
       });
   });
```

Comment: I think am adding my code in wrong place.page is getting refreshed after clicking the menu.so added active class may be hide right?

Comment: If your code inside $(function(){//yourcode}) or $(document).ready(function(){//your code});is not problem with refreshed page. Because the code execute after page has loaded or on document ready.

Comment: do not add the code inside onClick event. but put it on somewhere else.